# SearchBar changes color if initial state is invisible

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I add 2 search bars with **the same color**. One is visible, second is not:

```
<SearchBar Text="Visible" BackgroundColor="Lime" Margin="0, 100, 0, 0"></SearchBar>
<SearchBar x:Name="SearchBar1" IsVisible="false" BackgroundColor="Lime"></SearchBar>
<Button Text="Show" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Button>
```

Make second visible on button click:

```
async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SearchBar1.IsVisible = true;
}
```

As a result I have the second search bar in dark green, not lime as expected
[image: result]

Comment: This seems like a bug. When you set the isVisible from false to true ,the subview(imageView) of searchBar didn't set this value at same time.I have add a issue at github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4194. You can continuous attention

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by setting visibility to false OnAppearing event